# SQL: Mapping phases with a start and end date to a transaction table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the two tables, one with a list of start and end dates and one transactional with a list of expenditure.

Table 1: MilestonePhases

```
+-----------+------------------------------+------------+------------+
| ProjectID | MilestonePhase               | StartDate  | EndDate    |
+-----------+------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 1         | Planning/ Project Initiation | 1/01/2010  | 5/01/2010  |
+-----------+------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 1         | Design                       | 6/01/2010  | 10/01/2010 |
+-----------+------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 1         | Construction                 | 11/01/2010 | 18/01/2010 |
+-----------+------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 1         | Project Finalisation         | 19/01/2010 | 20/01/2010 |
+-----------+------------------------------+------------+------------+
```

Table 2: Expenditure

```
+-----------+-------------+
| Date      | Expenditure |
+-----------+-------------+
| 1/01/2010 | 482         |
+-----------+-------------+
| 2/01/2010 | 541         |
+-----------+-------------+
| 3/01/2010 | 840         |
+-----------+-------------+
| 4/01/2010 | 147         |
+-----------+-------------+
| 5/01/2010 | 297         |
+-----------+-------------+
| 6/01/2010 | 1185        |
+-----------+-------------+
| ...       | ...         |
+-----------+-------------+
```

I'm hoping to map the transactions to the start and end date of each phase and reproduce the following result however am having difficulty.

```
+-----------+-------------+------------------------------+
| Date      | Expenditure | MilestonePhase               |
+-----------+-------------+------------------------------+
| 1/01/2010 | 482         | Planning/ Project Initiation |
+-----------+-------------+------------------------------+
| 2/01/2010 | 541         | Planning/ Project Initiation |
+-----------+-------------+------------------------------+
| 3/01/2010 | 840         | Planning/ Project Initiation |
+-----------+-------------+------------------------------+
| 4/01/2010 | 147         | Planning/ Project Initiation |
+-----------+-------------+------------------------------+
| 5/01/2010 | 297         | Planning/ Project Initiation |
+-----------+-------------+------------------------------+
| 6/01/2010 | 1185        | Design                       |
+-----------+-------------+------------------------------+
| ...       | ...         | ...                          |
+-----------+-------------+------------------------------+
```

I can un-pivot the MilestonePhases table on join the tables together though I only join to the start and end date themselves which doesn't get me the milestone phase for each transaction

```
+-----------+-------------+------------------------------+
| Date      | Expenditure | MilestonePhase               |
+-----------+-------------+------------------------------+
| 1/01/2010 | 482         | Planning/ Project Initiation |
+-----------+-------------+------------------------------+
| 2/01/2010 | 541         |                              |
+-----------+-------------+------------------------------+
| 3/01/2010 | 840         |                              |
+-----------+-------------+------------------------------+
| 4/01/2010 | 147         |                              |
+-----------+-------------+------------------------------+
| 5/01/2010 | 297         | Planning/ Project Initiation |
+-----------+-------------+------------------------------+
| 6/01/2010 | 1185        | Design                       |
+-----------+-------------+------------------------------+
| ...       | ...         | ...                          |
+-----------+-------------+------------------------------+
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?
Thanks!

Comment: can you show your query

Comment: Apologies I am dummying up data. Table 2 also has also has project IDs to join too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `join`:

```
select e.*, mp. MilestonePhase
from expenditure e left join
     MilestonePhases mp
     on e.date >= mp.start and e.date <= mp.end;
```

This assumes that the dates are stored as dates and not strings.  If they are not, fix the data model so they are stored correctly.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of that. Thank you so much